# How can i convert canvas to bitmap for save in sdCard

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview, android-bitmap, surfaceholder

I use SurfaceView to move two bitmap picture over the screen.
I tried this:

```
...
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  super.onDraw(canvas);

  ...

  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,matrix,paint);
  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2,matrix,paint);
}
...
```

How it possible to save canvas into sdCard like this?

```
public saveCanvasIntoSdCard(Canvas canvas)
{

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution I found:

```
public Bitmap getBitmap() {
  Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap2.getWidth(), bitmap2.getHeight(), bitmap2.getConfig());
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 0, 0, null);
  return bmOverlay;
}

public void save(View view){
  String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
  File myDir = new File(root + "/dress");    
  myDir.mkdirs();

  String fname = "save.jpg";
  File file = new File (myDir, fname);
  if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
  try {
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
  getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
  out.flush();
  out.close();

  } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }

}
```

Comment: whats matrix? is it the identity matrix?